# Image thumbnails for a LiveBroadcast object

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I can't seem to associate image thumbnails with a LiveBroadcast object as per the documentation when trying to create a live stream via the API.

For my application, I am using the following reference:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#snippet.thumbnails

Here's an example of my payload sent to `/liveBroadcasts`:

```php
array:3 [
  "snippet" => array:5 [
    "title" => "Test broadcast"
    "description" => "Test description",
    "thumbnails" => array:1 [
      "default" => array:3 [
        "url" => "my-image"
        "width" => 120
        "height" => 90
      ]
    ]
    "scheduledStartTime" => "2021-03-01T21:35:37.000000Z"
    "scheduledEndTime" => "2021-03-01T21:40:37.000000Z"
  ]
  "contentDetails" => array:2 [
    "enableAutoStart" => true
    "enableAutoStop" => true
  ]
  "status" => array:1 [
    "privacyStatus" => "public"
  ]
]
```

The URL to `my-image` of course is actually a working URL.

Must the images in `thumbnails` be previously uploaded to YouTube and hosted there instead? What else could I be missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According to the official specs of the [`LiveBroadcasts.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert) and [`LiveBroadcasts.update`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/update) API endpoints, you're not allowed to set the respective live broadcast resource object's `thumbnails` property when invoking either of these endpoints:

Neither the [request body](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert#request-body) of the former endpoint, nor the [request body](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/update#request-body) of the latter one has specified the property `thumbnails` among those accepted to be initialized or, respectively, modified.

For to update your live broadcast's thumbnails, you have to use the [`Thumbnails.set`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set) API endpoint instead, invoked appropriately with its request parameter [`videoId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set#videoId) set to the [ID](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#id) of your broadcast.

For PHP (though it's not clear from your post what's your programming language/environment), look for the official Google sample code that is uploading thumbnails to YouTube using `Thumbnails.set`: [upload_thumbnail.php](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/upload_thumbnail.php).

Answer (score 0):

Context: Using the PHP api.

After a successful INSERT, you can do the following:

```
$google_service_youtube->thumbnails->set('', [
  'videoId' => $insert_response->getid(),
  'data' => file_get_contents($imgfilename),
  'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',  # or image/png
  'uploadType' => 'multipart',
]);
```

$imagefilename can be local or a url.