# Youtube API for automation on Thumbnail and endscreen

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-data-api

My Question is about YouTube thumbnails and endscreens

We are trying to automate publishing of content for YouTube channels. Can thumbnail be automatically set for the given episode with details such as show logo, episode number from the content.

Looking for API to support the automation.

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0):

There's the following API endpoint that permits you to set the thumbnail of your videos (thus, of [your broadcasts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66544512/8327971) too): [`Thumbnails.set`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set).

For what concerns Python, I'd recommend to read, understand and use the public sample code from Google: [`upload_thumbnail.py`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/upload_thumbnail.py).

Note that in case you need uploading a thumbnail for a broadcast, then simply use that broadcast's ID as the parameter `videoId` that you'll pass to the `Thumbnails.set` API endpoint call.